# Allow PHP sessions to carry over to subdomains

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies

I use PHP sessions (not cookies, except for session id cookie) for all user data, and when a user goes to their profile `user.mydomain.example` they are immediately "logged out" until then remove the subdomain.

Is there a way to accept sessions from all domains as long as its `*.mydomain.example`

Comment: First, `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com')`, *then* `session_start()` or `Session::start()` from https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie

Answer (score 99):

Here are 4 options.

Place this in your php.ini:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

Or in your .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

Or as the first thing in your script:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

Or in your php-fpm pool configuration for your site:

```
php_value[session.cookie_domain] = .example.com
```

Comment: Unfortunately all 3 failed to work, does there need to be a star * ?

Comment: Very strange, I've used the those methods before and they work fine.  Do you by chance have Suhosin installed, I remember there be a setting that needed to be changed to allow this? If you don't, can you post more info about your install (eg. apache, lighttpd, php version)?

Comment: some packages come with Suhosin on it. `php -i | grep -i 'Suhosin'` to see if it's there

Comment: i had disabled suhosin, etc etc, everything on every board everywhere, my answer below was all that i could get to work.  i checked my phpinfo and all, the domain was set, suhosin encryption off, and it still was regenerating a new session id every time i'd enter a new subdomain.

Comment: @CTT please add a forth option to your answer:

`session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'example.com', false, false);`

Comment: Dont forget to actually close the browser then open it again. Otherwise your going to go in circles! .. i did

Comment: Another reminder for dumb people like me: make sure `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');` comes _before_ `session_start();`

Comment: Remember to clear our the previous session before trying these by restarting Apache.

Comment: ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' ); this one worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: IMPORTANT: If you have a different php versions running on main site and other version on "subdomain" - NOTHING OF THIS WILL WORK ! I've spent 4hours debugging php sessions and then I've realized that main domain was running on php 7.1 and subdomain was on 5.6... so if above solutions doesn't work and no error is thrown- CHECK PHP VERSION ! ...also check session.save_path they must match for main site and subdomain !

Comment: Adding to this: if you call your PHP script that handles the sessions from a single page application you have to add:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
and set withCredentials: true for the xhrFields when making a request;
more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002038/setting-a-cookie-on-a-subdomain-from-an-ajax-request

Answer (score 13):

```
        if(isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
            session_id($_COOKIE['session_id']);
        Zend_Session::start(); //or session_start();
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
            setcookie('session_id', session_id(), 0, '/', '.yourdomain.example');
```

security be damned, if you are as frustrated with incomplete or bad answers as I am, this is your savior. It just works.

Comment: this worked for me, but I don't understand the security issue. Would you mind explaining what security issues might be there?

Answer (score 6):

change the session name at the top of the core functions file
like

```
 session_name('mysession');
```

then use the following code into the php page

```
  session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".example.com",FALSE,FALSE);
  setcookie(session_name(), session_id(),0,"/","example.com");
  session_start();
```

finally change the default session name of the subdomain and remove the default cookie in subdomain's core functions file
like:

```
 /*default session name*/
 session_name("mysession");
 /*remove the PHPSESSID and default session name from subdomain's cookie*/
 setcookie( "mysession", "",1,"/" );
 setcookie( "PHPSESSID", "",1,"/" );
```

if you continue with using your cookie name as PHPSESSID ,just remove all the functions with

```
 "mysession" string like session_name('mysession'), setcookie( "mysession", "",1,"/" );
```

then check your browser's existing cookies, just remove all the cookies of domain and subdomain, and repeat the process.

Comment: This did the job for me.  None of other answers in this question worked.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is quite old - but to further expand on @CTT's suggestion - I needed to add a php.ini file in each sub-directory (that will be executing php code and requires the session) of my subdomain with the following text:

```
suhosin.session.cryptdocroot=Off
suhosin.cookie.cryptdocroot=Off
```

I hope this helps (it took me ages to figure this out).

Comment: This one is evil, been debugging for 2 hours now, as session sharing been working fine on my local environment.
should have checked suhosin settings earlier

Answer (score 4):

Another option that worked for me: is to force the name of the session:

```
session_name("myWebsite");
session_start();
```

Comment: This by far seems like the simplest solution

Answer (score 4):

yes. `ini_set` is working. but remember to destroy all caches and cookies of the browser to see it works.

1. destroy all caches and cookies of your browser
2. in your `xxx.example.com` and `yyy.example.com`, your php files should start like this.

   ```
   ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' ); session_start();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and it turns out I was using different php.ini files for two different sub-domains. These ini files specified different [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) variables. For obvious reasons this needs to be the same for all sub-domains that need to share sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
session_start();

$sessionId =  session_id();
```

logged the user. When user will switch to other subdomain sent the session id in the URL like this `user.mydomain.example/?id=$sessionId`

```
$sessionId =  $_GET['id'];

session_start($sessionId);
```

Now the user will get all the session values and stay logged in.

Comment: If your answer starts with "try this" you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Before `session_start()` use `session_set_cookie_params()` replacing `.domain.example` with your domain like this example:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.example');
session_start();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
    session_id($_COOKIE['session_id']);
    Zend_Session::start(); //or session_start();

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
        setcookie('session_id', session_id(), 0, '/', '.yourdomain.example');
```

This is a good solution, but you cannot use it in all situations. For examples it will not work when you cannot rely on not-session cookies.

This actually MUST work if you use it correctly.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

For example you need to put it before `session_start()` and also in all files that call `session_start()`