# Why can't I pass user sessions between subdomains?

Tags: php, session, cookies

First of all, I have used ALL of the suggested methods in this SO article:
[Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

For your convenience, here are the tips I already followed:

> Here are 3 options.
>
> Place this in your php.ini:
>
> ```
> session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
> ```
>
> In your .htaccess:
>
> ```
> php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
> ```
>
> As the first thing in your script:
>
> ```
> ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.example.com' );
> ```

I have 9 subdomains (losangeles.mysite.com, sandiego.mysite.com, etc), and I would like users to be able to stay signed in between them. As of now, however, the server is treating each subdomain as a fully contained site with separate sessions.

Is there anything else I can do? Or how can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you checked what value is actually used in the Set-Cookie header field?

Comment: yup, in both the .ini AND in my script it is set to ".mysite.com" .. which should theoretically pass it, right?

Comment: Theoretically. But have you looked into the HTTP header of the response you got from the server?

Comment: Why was this closed due to thanks answers?  There are just 2 of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the cookies are being set for .foo.example.com instead of .example.com. Try installing the Live HTTP Headers add-on for Firefox and checking what the cookies are getting set as.

To do this, open Live HTTP Headers and with the window open, go to the page that sets the cookie. In the window, there should be a line that looks like this.

Set-Cookie: lng=en-US; path=/; domain=.example.com;

If the cookie is set for domain=.foo.example.com; then you know what the problem is. However, if the domain is .example.com, something else is going on.

Also, if the cookies are getting set for .example.com on foo.example.com, check to see if the browser is sending cookies to bar.example.com. This should help track down where the problem is.

Comment: okay, so i found the SET-COOKIE, and it indeed says domain=.mysite.com

Comment: ALSO, i do set cookies on the client's machine, and they seem to be passing just fine between the subdomains...could that mean something?

Comment: If cookies are being sent to the different sub domains, it sounds like this is a red herring. There is probably a problem somewhere else in the code.

Comment: the hell...it just started working RANDOMLY. i haven't touched the code since opening this question. I wonder if the php5.ini hadn't "activated" yet or something

Comment: Changes to php.ini usually don't take effect until your HTTP server has been restarted.

Comment: I LOVE YOU BUDDY - i have been trying to figure this out for forever!!!!!!. Nothing logical to post just my extreme gratitude -