# Weird behaviour of Zend_Session_Namespace

Tags: zend-framework, session

Follow up to this:

[Why can't I pass user sessions between subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795414/why-cant-i-pass-user-sessions-between-subdomains)

I followed the advice there and used :

```php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','mydomain');
```

(with and without a dot before mydomain) as the first line of `index.php` in the public folder as advised there and in other links around the web.
The problem is that it completely "ruined" `Zend_Session_Namespace` inside my application.

While it persisted among calls (as it should) of the page, now every time it is being called it is behaving as a new session is being instantiated, without holding all variables.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the cookie domain via Zend_Session?

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = 'mydomain';

Zend_Session::setOptions($config);
```

Comment: yes, and it did not work:

$sessionOptions = array( );
$sessionOptions['cookie_domain'] = BASE_SITE;

Zend_Session::setOptions($sessionOptions);
Zend_Session::start();

Comment: I found a solution after many months, until now I used a workaround:
inside php.ini of apache:
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
which is the same as the "same" question in the link above.
Afterwards the apache needs obviously a restart, but the the browser's cache and sessions need to be cleaned as well to test from "new".
After that I only used more than one session namespaces to have domain specific variables in each.