# php session variable doesnt carry over to redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, header, session-variables

**Problem: Session variable doesnt carry over after the redirect.**

facebook.php (session variable created, and stored)

button directs to available.php --> searching.php

I'm using header redirect. So $_SESSION['seshfbId'] echos on available.php but not searching.php

Code

facebook.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 

header( 'Location: http://www.redacted.co/chat.php' ) ;
function createSeshVariables($name, $email, $college, $photo, $id)
{
// set the value of the session variable 'name'
$_SESSION['seshName'] = $name;

// set the value of the session variable 'email'
$_SESSION['seshEmail'] = $email;

// set the value of the session variable 'education'
$_SESSION['seshEducation'] = $college;

// set the value of the session variable 'photolink'
$_SESSION['seshPhotolink'] = $photo;
// set the value of the session variable 'photolink'
$_SESSION['seshfbId'] = $id;
}

createSeshVariables($fbName,$fbEmail,$fbCollege,$photolink,$fbId); 
?>
```

available.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 
header( 'Location: http://www.redacted.co/assets/php/searching.php' );
echo $_SESSION['seshfbId'];
//if i comment out header redirect the echo works here.
changeStatusToAvailable($_SESSION['seshfbId']); 
?>
```

searching.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // start up your PHP session!
echo $_SESSION['seshfbId'];
?>
```

**EDIT: after vardump i have found seshId and seshToken on the searching page. but the code used to create that is on tac.php. I have a feeling tac.php code clashed with session variables earlier**

tac.php

```
$apiObj = new OpenTokSDK(API_Config::API_KEY, API_Config::API_SECRET);
$session = $apiObj->createSession( $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],                array(SessionPropertyConstants::P2P_PREFERENCE=> "enabled") );
$seshId = $session->getSessionId();
$_SESSION['seshId'] = $seshId;
$token = $apiObj->generate_token($seshId, RoleConstants::PUBLISHER, null);
$_SESSION['seshToken'] = $token;
```

Comment: If you `var_dump($_SESSION)`, does it contain any of the variables you previously set? What about `session_id()`, do you get the same session ID across all pages?

Comment: You can use Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools to look at the requests as they're happening. Check if the last page in that redirect chain gets the same `PHPSESSID` cookie.

Comment: see this pages i think you want pass session between subdomains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795414/why-cant-i-pass-user-sessions-between-subdomains and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains

Comment: Did the vardump, all the session variable is et in facebook.php was correctly dumped on available.php

on searching.php its interesting because there are session variables but different ones set from this code on another page.

edited question to reflect this new code.

Comment: I know i am probably wrong, but to point out what appears obvious have you tried moving the header location to the bottom of setting the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. As i suspected the opentok API clashed with my sesh variables because it invoked the session variables. i moved all the session variables to one php and problem solved.