# session.cookie_domain not working on all browsers

Tags: php, session-cookies

The following code sets the session cookie as follow:

```
ini_set( 'session.cookie_domain', 'mysite.com' );
```

- FF header - domain=.mysite.com
- IE header - domain=mysite.com (no initial dot)
- Cr header - domain=.mysite.com

---

The following code sets the session cookie as follow:

```
ini_set( 'session.cookie_domain', 'dev.mysite.com' );
```

- FF - domain=.dev.mysite.com (works)
- IE - domain=mysite.com (ignores subdomain; uses root domain, no initial dot)
- Cr - failed to create session

---

Trying to set the Session cookie to a particular subdomain, so that sub1.dev.mysite.com, sub2.dev.mysite.com could access the same Session cookie. But, it only works with FF.

---

Set session name to something like SESS_NAME.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795414 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920 if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, none of their solutions works. It looks like this is a browser issue, because of how each implements it in their output. For example, Chrome does not even work if I include a subdomain. It works fine with FF. And IE ignores it and uses the root domain instead.

Is it possible that Chrome and IE is missing something in the header that they are unable to properly process it? And FF uses default values?

Comment: From Fiddler, the raw header is the same on all browsers. Here I am setting it to dev.mysite.com

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2013 19:48:39 GMT
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: SESS_NAME=70nd4k6n1c8c1jt899sm1rk1d7; path=/; domain=dev.mysite.com
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Status: 200
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 74632
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, I found that Chrome does not like underscore. SESS_NAME vs SESSNAME.