# Can't share PHP sessions between subdomain and main

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain, session-cookies

I want to make a session on a subdomain, and then access it from my main domain. I have read many threads regarding the same problem but none of the answers work for me.

I have a VPS from Dreamhost, and I have sat the following line into phprc on both domains (phprc is added to php.ini, dreamhost way of editing php.ini) session.cookie_domain = ".MAINDOMAIN.com" where .MAINDOMAIN.com is referring to my domain name. This was the working solution here: [Sharing SESSION Variables Between Multiple Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains)

I have then made a php file I call test.php on both login.DOMAIN.com and DOMAIN.com

On login.DOMAIN.com/test.php I have the following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = "Works";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

The output when I navigate to the file:

> Array ( [test] => Works )

After visiting that page I Then go to DOMAIN.com/test.php where the code is:

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

And the output is:

> Array ( )

I have seen other threads like this: [Allow PHP sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains) with 4 different options to set the php.ini line (Directly in php.ini, in .htaccess, in the script, and finally php-fpm pool configuration) and I have tried them all with the exception of the last one with php-fpm pool configuration

I have also tried to set this line on top of my php files, before session_start:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".MAINDOMAIN.com",FALSE,FALSE);
```

And this on top of that:

```
session_name('mysession');
```

But nothing works

I have also checked with HTTP Header Live for FF which domain the cookie is set for as the answer here: [Why can't I pass user sessions between subdomains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795414/why-cant-i-pass-user-sessions-between-subdomains) and the string of Set-Cookie is:

> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9Q%2Cfrhr747fferf4700; path=/

There is no mention of what domain? What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a limitation on Dremhost managed VPS, that don't allow sharing php sessions between virtual hosts (Subdomains). I have switched to another provider and everything works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more of a work around but...

if you're not passing any private information you could pass the information from the sub domain to domain with $_GET's then use a page (getsession.php) on the domain to turn the $_GET's to $_SESSION's and redirect back to index of the domain to remove the $_GET's from url.

Comment: It is going to be session for logged in users, and therefore extremely private, unfortunately :(