# Does PHP set by default the session cookie for all subdomains?

Tags: php, session

I wonder how this quote from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) should be interpreted:

> session.cookie_domain specifies the domain to set in the session
>   cookie. Default is none at all meaning the host name of the server
>   which generated the cookie according to cookies specification.

Does it mean that when calling `session_start` on URL www.somedomain.com/somepage.php the cookie will have the following form:

```
Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=e48gh5mqggccgmn8172f0j5a06; path=/; domain=.somedomain.com
```

Or

```
Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=e48gh5mqggccgmn8172f0j5a06; path=/; domain=www.somedomain.com
```

I have seen on index pages the first cookie header and on other pages a header without a domain.

Can someone bring some insight on this?

Thanks

Comment: [Some nice answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, php will usualy set the cookie for the current domain ex: wwww.domain.com.
To have everything consistent, you must either redirect all request to the same domain, or explicitly set the cookie for all subdomains.

EDIT: actualy, this is true for Firefox. I think PHP will not actualy set the domain, so the browser is free to use whatever he wants. Internet Explorer i think will set it for any subdomain

Comment: Thanks. PHP actually wouldn't bother to set the domain so the cookie it wil send is: `Set-Cookie  PHPSESSID=e48gh5mqggccgmn8172f0j5a06; path=/` which is left for the browser to interpret. Further investigation is needed to figure which browsers do what but I guess it is not that important.

Answer (score 2):

No PHP by default never set session cookie for all subdomains.

If you want to set a cookie across all subdomains then you can do this by using this code:

```
<?php
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

$rootDomain = '.example.com';

session_set_cookie_params(
    $currentCookieParams["lifetime"],
    $currentCookieParams["path"],
    $rootDomain,
    $currentCookieParams["secure"],
    $currentCookieParams["httponly"]
);

session_name('mysessionname');
session_start();

setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue, time() + 3600, '/', $rootDomain);
?>
```

For reference please visit http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 1):

It does set the cookie for the domain visible in the client's browser (so, option 2 in your question). If you want to set a cookie for all subdomains you should call [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and put `".domain.com"` in the `$domain` parameter.