# how to Link php login form to another website

Tags: php, html, database

I have a login form in PHP and MySQL for example in a domain named "login.example.com" and I want it to login to another website for example "home.example.com" at the same time that I login into the first domain, how can I do it without using cookies?

The values that I want to transfer between the domains is the email and the password.

```
$email       =  e($_POST['email']);                                                            //The email of the user
$password  =  e($_POST['password']);                                                       //The password of the user
```

Comment: The question i linked didnt have a lot of information but this has already been answered here. I cant edit my mark as duplicate but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497864/does-php-set-by-default-the-session-cookie-for-all-subdomains

Comment: with out knowing how the login system works, its impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options,

1. After login approved, redirect to the second domain (subdomain) and set the session there too
2. After login approved, load a pixel image with the URL of your second domain (subdomain) EX :

   echo "< img href='https://sub.example.com' />"

In both option, you have to run the script on your second domain (subdomain) to set the session

**Update**

Example to set a session :

```
$_SESSION['login'] = $id;
```

**Update 2**

It's not a good practice to transfer email and password between domains (subdomains), it's not secure, but you can setting cookie or session to identify the email and password with a unique ID which could be transferred between domains (subdomains)

Comment: This provides an unnecessary way of doing this. The setcookie() function can handle setting a cookie that is available to all subdomains.

Comment: Read the question :S it said Without using cookie ! @castis