# Session not starting when using www

Tags: php, session, dns, session-variables, session-cookies

I have a strange problem here.

I am using a directory script running off PHP.

The users have the option to type in their postcode so the directory can use their postcode to find local businesses.

I am using a session to save their postcode.

The problem is when the session postcode ($_SESSION['postcode']) doesn't show when I leave out the "www." in the domain. How can I set it so the postcode will show with/without the www.?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: please provide a little more details, or a part of the script?

Comment: Check your session cookie's domain settings. If the cookie is set for `wwww.domain.com`, it will not be available for `other.domain.com` or `domain.com`.

Comment: Is there a way I can set it for both domains or should I use the rewrite engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains see this thread.

Comment: Solved,  I actually read another thread from here that solved it.  Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it worked :)

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mywebsite.org
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.org/$1 [R=permanent,L]