# Sharing SESSION Variables Between Multiple Subdomains

Tags: php, subdomain, session-variables

I have a website www.example.com. That will have multiple subdomains that work with a single application or program. For an example, login.example.com will allow the user to log in to the site while system.example.com will allow the user to access an information system, while forums.example.com will allow the user to access forums.

We may need to pass information between the subdomains such as a user id, or a user preference, etc. How do we go about passing information between the sudomains using SESSION variables?

EDIT:
I like this idea:

As the first thing in your script:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

Comment: Do you plan on using the SAME session on all of the subdomains or would you like the session information to be isolated by subdomain?  If you ever expand and move one subdomain to another physical server, this could be problematic if you share the session across all domains.  Or you would have to switch to memory/database based session storage which all servers could access.

Comment: I plan to use the SAME session on all the subdomains. However another drawback may be that I have multiple domains on one sever. What would I do then to keep the sessions separte amongst the regular domains, but keep them for the subdomains only?

Answer (score 18):

1) the subdomains should use the same path to save session files

2) modify your

php.ini `session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`

or .htaccess `php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com`

or inside of the script `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );`

Comment: What if you are using a hosting service where you have more than one domain. Example would be example1.com, example2.com, example3.com. Then what would you do?

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu   Nothing by the cookies, it does not work this way. You could attach session id to the links leading to another domain, at another domain you get this session id and start session with. The requirement about shared session folders is still here.

Comment: How do I get the sessiom id to put in the links?

Comment: Furthermore, how do I get the other page to read and use it? haha. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu look at http://www.php.net/session_id  use at, attach this ID as argument to the URLs leading to another domain. Use it to set the same session id on it. The best way is not to match it directly to the authentication session, otherwise if user is not logged out and submits this link to somebody else then they will have access to his data.

Comment: When you mean inside of the script in your answer did you mean inside the script of the webpage?

Comment: @KevinOluseunKarimu  I meant inside of the script that starts the session or changes session variables.

Answer (score 16):

PHP session ids are saved in Cookies. **To make a cookie available in all the sub-domains you need to assign it to the root domain**. Then all the sub-domains will get the session id from cookie and PHP can find the session using passed session id.

As it turns out, You just need to set the `session.cookie_domain` to the root domain in `php.ini` file

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

Also check [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) for different approaches used to set an ini entry.

Comment: What if you are using a hosting service where you have more than one domain. Example would be example1.com, example2.com, example3.com. Then what would you do?

Comment: Add `php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com` in `.htaccess` file for each of your domains

Comment: I'm sorry so you would add that as "php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com?" Correct?

Comment: The way my hosting service has set this up is to have a .htaccess for each directory. I don't see one for each domain.

Comment: put it in root directory or example.com. If you have `example.com/index.php` file then put the `.htaccess` in the directory where `index.php` is kept. Thats the document root.

Answer (score 11):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
session_name("2620368ghwahw90w");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();
```

This appears to work with no problem. Is this a good method with low security risk?

Answer (score 3):

Before you create your session in php file, add this line at first line :

```
<?php
//session cross to sub domain
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"."),100));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use cookies. check the `path` parameter in [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) which makes that cookie available for he entire domain. drawbacks to this are people who turn off cookies (private browsing modes)

another method would be by [passing the sessionID around using links](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) or hidden `<input>` fields (for forms).

since separate websites don't share sessions (as far as i know, since subdomains are technically "different places" from eachother), don't use sessions to store on the server side. instead, use a database to handle your sessions. that way, multiple sites can share the same session tracking table.

Comment: What if you are using a hosting service where you have more than one domain. Example would be example1.com, example2.com, example3.com. Then what would you do?

Answer (score 0):

To share the session cookie among subdomains, you have to set the cookie's domain to `.example.org` (mind the dot).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

Answer (score 0):

I have been going round with this for a while now and what worked for me is placing the code below:

`session_name("some_session_name");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.some_domain.com');
session_start();`

across all the sub-domains that will use the session variables. I set this at the beginning of my index php file and it works. Hope this will make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Works like charm!

I believe the cleanest way is to create in you .env a variable `SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.com`

Alternatively, you can open up `config/session.php` and set `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.example.com')`,
with that all subdomains eg. `domain.example.com`, `test.example.com` even `example.com` shares same session

Answer (score 0):

This should work in *most*, if not all, cases:

```
<?php

if (!session_id()) /* If session is not started yet, then... */
    {
        ini_set('session.cookie_domain', substr_count($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],'.') > 1 ? ('.'.substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '.') + 1)) : ('.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));
        session_start(); /* Start session now. */
    };
    
?>
```

Comment: The problem with @Pathic 's answer is if you visit the page without a subdomain at all, then your `session.cookie_domain` will be set to `'.com'` which matches most of the domains on the internet. Not secure at all, if it even works. :(