# How to get session variable in Subdomain in PHP

Tags: php, session

I have a website `www.example.com`. Subdomain is `sub.example.com`. I am using shared server, so I cant access php.ini. In www.example.com login page I am using

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["UserId"]=$UserId;
```

So thab I can use `$_SESSION["UserId"]`. But when I try to access session in sub.example.com it failed. No session available. How I get session variables in subdomain. What are the codes for example.com and also for sub.example.com.

Comment: there's no codes. you just need to check that your session cookie settings allow for subdomain use. there's any number of other questions on this site for that sort of thing. Once you get the cookies sorted out, the sessions should "Just work".

Comment: @MarcB Sir how can i create a cookie in main domain and set UserId in cookie. How i access cookie in subdomain. How to find whether userid exist or not by using php script

Comment: @Nidhi You can read PHP manual or add new question. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

try this put it at the head of the php file, i've used this before

```
session_name("mySession");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
$_SESSION['UserId'] = $UserId;
```

Comment: sir where i put this code? i want to put $_SESSION["UserId"] in cookie. how possible

Comment: i edited it but i havent tested it yet run it and get back to me