# Setting PHP session ONLY on subdomain FROM domain

Tags: php, ajax, session

I got a system, where each client has their own subdomain. The users can log into the system directly from their own subdomain, but I want to add the opportunity to login directly from the domain, and afterwards send them to the subdomain.
It is important that the session is only set on the actual subdomain, and not on any other subdomains or the main domain.

All login-processes are made through jQuery/AJAX.

I've tried the following:

- On domain.com a user fills out the login-form, and a call is made to domain.com/ajax/front-login.php
- From this AJAX-file the user is validated, the subdomain that the user belongs to is found, and a PHP POST-call (through file_get_contents) is made to subdomain.domain.com/ajax/sub-login.php. This file validates and sets a SESSION.
- From the callback it looks like everything is done correctly, but the session is not set on subdomain.domain.com

I hope it makes sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say the session is not set on the subdomain, how are you checking that? Are you just looking for the cookie in the browser? Or did you redirect to the subdomain and try to dump out the session?

Comment: i don't know if that's what you need but check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains

Comment: @JeremyHarris If the session was set, the user would have access - the user has not and needs to login.

Comment: @Tony If it works when targeting a specific subdomain it might work.

Comment: Do you set the session on a subdomain.domain.com php file? EDIT: you set the session on sub-login.php as you said. So you set it in a sub-domain file. So the session is not saved on the sub-domain but to the domain? If that's the case maybe it has something to do with ajax

Comment: Your 100% certain that the session starts in `sub-login.php`? with `session_start()`, check your session settings so that it doesn't auto start or starts in `front-login.php`, http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

Answer (score 0):

Add `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', $subdomain.'.domain.com');` to the beginning of`subdomain.domain.com/ajax/sub-login.php`, where you feed $subdomain with it's name.

Remove `session_start()` from `front-login.php` or atleast wrap it in a `if ()` statement if there is no subdomain.

Comment: can you add `front-login.php` and `sub-login.php` to the post? if it didn't work, the session must start before the `ini_set()`.

Comment: So the ini_set needs to come before session_start()?

Comment: Just tested - no difference. First ini_set, then session_start(), then the session is set. But yeah, I have session_start() in front-login.php too, but how does that make a difference?

Comment: Then the session starts in `front-login.php`