# I can have the same session for two Laravel projects?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.1

I have two laravel projects in te same server (**mydomain.com** and **sub.mydomain.com**) with different database but the user ID's are the same.

I want the session to be the same on both platforms, How I do this? It is posible?

Comment: You could store your session data in redis or memcache and in session.php configuration file set the cookie to be available on all subdomains. I think that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [This answser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains), you have first to set the cookie domain to ".example.com" to enable sharing accross subdomains.

To answer in a more laravel specific way, you have to change the 'domain' value in the config/session.php file. Beware of implications when in local environment.

Also some things are to be taken into consideration. If the two domains are differents laravel APP, please ensure that they are sharing the SAME APP KEY so that cookies are valid on both apps and that they share the same session storage (same db table, or same folder path, adjust to whatever driver you use).

Beware that by sharing the APP KEY, compromising one app will enable the attacker to probably access the other one. (make sense as a real user that have access to one, will have access to the other). To be more secure, look into oauth providers that will enable the user to access apps with a single shared login system.