# PHP sessions aren't available on multiple website

Tags: php, session

On my website, I need to share vars `$_SESSION` with an other website based on the same VPS.

I already test it but the vars `$_SESSION` didn't pass to the other website.
But the configuration of the `$_SESSION` location is the same.

What should I check ?

Sorry for my English, I am French :)

Matancy

Comment: Do you access the other website with the same domain name? That is, is your web site example.com/mysite and the other site example.com/othersite? If not, what's your setup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains might help for same domain.

Comment: My website does not have the same domain or subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is that you must have a shared resource to share sessions among different hosts - be it a SQL database, memcached, a NoSQL database, etc. that all servers can access. You then use session_set_save_handler to access the shared resource.

Comment: In many server configurations there is a shared `/tmp` location for session files. The problem (better said "security feature") is the same origin policy of cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Your `$_SESSION` vars are only available inside the server where you're working on. Try this on any .php page of your project with

```
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

to understand better the working of the `$_SESSION` vars;

Comment: On the website the session works without problems.
But when i go to an onther website hosted on the same VPS, the session will be different.

Comment: You have to resort to another alternative like SQL, such as the Quasimodo's clone suggested above; If it were possible to do as you wish, the $ _SESSION vars would be unsafe to use;