# access sessions and cookies of another laravel app inside the larave app that resides on same server

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies, laravel-6

I have this scenario where I have 4 websites built with Laravel 6 and all of them resides on same server and all of them are subdomains e.g.

> https://account.mywebsite.com
>
> https://business.mywebsite.com
>
> https://realestate.mywebsite.com
>
> https://deals.mywebsite.com

the issue is in https://account.mywebsite.com, if I'm authenticated there already, the rest of the Laravel websites must be also authenticated so simply a single sign in mechanism. What I'm thinking right now, If I can access the authentication session or cookie from the account website (https://account.mywebsite.com), or from the account subdomain set a custom auth cookie/session then the rest of the Laravel websites access that auth cookie/session then I can authenticate the rest of the Laravel websites. I believe, each Laravel store unique session and cookie.

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
Cookie::get('name');
```

so any ideas, help on how to access a cookie or session from other Laravel app that is also on same server?

Comment: It wasn't easier to create a single web app and use the [sub domain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) feature?

Comment: This will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153716/sharing-session-variables-between-multiple-subdomains

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to change the domain of the cookies to the root domain (without the subdomain). That way all subdomains will have access to them.

Set [the `SESSION_DOMAIN` setting](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L145) in your `.env` file:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=mywebsite.com
```

Note: Laravel uses the `APP_NAME` for the [session cookie name](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/session.php#L116), so if your Laravel installations have different `APP_NAME`s they will not share the same session. If you want them to share the same session you can manually set the `SESSION_COOKIE`.