# PHP session works on all subdomains

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

How to setup user php `$_SESSION` to work in all subdomains?
Like Google makes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to take in account while sharing `$_SESSION` across subdomains.

1. Are all subdomains on ran by the same server?

   1. If not, then, you will need to share sessions amongst servers, there are several solutions:

      - Use NFS (not recommended)
      - Move SESSION to another storage (Database, Memcache, Redis) (best option imho)
   2. If they are, you may just need to configure your cookie domain using `session.cookie_domain` ini directive.
2. Are you running Suhosin, if you do, you may need to disable some security options to allow your session to be decrypted on the others servers.

Comment: Take at the [php manual](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) to know how to set such directive

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to find out how to make your session cookie accessible to your domain