# Same multi-domain session but session values lost

Tags: php, session, subdomain, session-variables, session-cookies

i've a problem with session on my multi-domain website.

In fact, i've :

- www.website.com

and

- my-account.website.com

In the php.ini, i've set : `session.cookie_domain = ".website.com"`

I check if it correctly change with `phpinfo();` and it's ok, i've well the same value for both website (domaine and sub-domain) :

- the same `session.cookie_domain`, `session.save_path`, `session.cookie_path`.
- `session.cookie_lifetime` = 0 and `session.cookie_secure` is off

Well, now, when i try some test :

- Define a session_name on www.website.com, start the session, define un session value like `$_SESSION["test"] = "myvalue";` and i display the session_id.
- Go to my-account.website.com and open the session with the same session name, i check the session id and i found the same id with www.website.com, but i have lost the session value that i defined. S_SESSION["test"] is lost.

Conclusion, the session id is kept, but sessions values are lost.

Any idea ? I have check to change with `session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.website.com');`
on each website. And also try to use the htaccess `php_value session.cookie_domain ".website.com"`

HELP, THAT MADE ME CRAZY.

Comment: Does your hosting environment uses the [suhoshin patchset](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/)? It could be used to encrypt the session values with (among others) the domain they are coming from, so one domain can't read other domain's cookies. (useful in shared hosting)

Comment: I'm not on a shared hosting, but on a OVH private server, Debian 6 with Apache. But it's very strange because i've worked on the sharing session between sub-domain 3 month ago and that worked fine, but when i worked on it again 1 week ago, nothing work :/ Reboot et relaunch apache and server solve anything.

Comment: `phpinfo()` tells you if you got sushoshin or not, but if my memory serves me right the default php install on debian includes it. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11657470/1515540) it might help.

Comment: Ok i try to turn of sushoshin with `php_value suhosin.session.cryptdocroot off` on any .htaccess.  

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.website.com'); 
session_start(); 

echo session_id().'<br>';

echo $_SESSION["test"];

I define TEST on my-account.website.com i try to display it here. Session_ID are the same, but TEST is lost on www.website.com.

Comment: Suhosin has nothing to do with this. If it did - you wouldn't get the same session ID as that is the only thing contained in the session cookie. What's your session.save_path?

Comment: my `session.cookie_path` is `/`

Answer (score 0):

After unsuccessfull search, i have re-install apache2 on my Debian. The problem was solved and session values are shared successfully.

I think my apache2 was corrupted by a plugin installation 2 month ago.