# Sharing $_SESSION across subdomains and keep alive

Tags: php, ajax, session, subdomain

I'm developping this website where each subdomain is a service, I wanted the user accounts to work on ever subdomains and users not having to relog everytime they switch from a subdomain to another so I'm using this code:

```
session_name("login");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.my_domain.com');
session_start();
```

It works very well, now my problem is with the keep alive, since some subdomains host single page applications, I have to do ajax calls to keep the PHP session alive, instead of putting a `keep_alive.php` file per subdomains (which would be the exact same file) I'm trying to use a single `keep_alive.php` file on one subdomain and do all the ajax calls on this file.

The problem is it doesn't work when the call is made from a different subdomain.

Example:

My `keep_alive.php` file is hosted on `static.my_domain.com`

If I try to call it from `pics.my_domain.com` it says `$_SESSION` isn't set, but if I call it from `static.my_domain.com` it works.

My `.htaccess` file already accepts `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from other subdomains.
I'm kind of stuck.

It it possible or my only solution is to copy the keep_alive.php file for each subdomain / create a symlink?

Comment: Show this question i think you help it. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091445/share-session-on-subdomains-in-php)