# How to access session on all subdomain

Tags: php, session

I want to access session on all subdomains. Both subdomains are on same server. I have added the line below in `.htaccess`:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .domain.com
```

Also in `php.ini`, `session.auto_start` is set as `on`

Your help with some code examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try article [**php-sessions-across-sub-domains**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains) or [**php-session-is-getting-reset-between-subdomains**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653603/php-session-is-getting-reset-between-subdomains) may these article's link help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064243/php-sessions-across-sub-domains

Comment: I can't see suhosin.session.cryptua, suhosin.session.cryptdocroot in my phpinfo. rest other things i have added in .htaccess.
also on both subdomain session id is defferent

Comment: when you dont see the `suhosin` configuration parts on your php.ini, you must **install the suhosin extension**

Comment: Actually it work just by doing session.auto_start and session.cookie_domain but only for one day. so did not get why it is not working now. Any idea?