# Why is $_SESSION emptied?

Tags: session, session-variables, php, sessionid

According to [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains), there are 3 ways to allow PHP sessions across different subdomains.

- php.ini: `session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`
- .htaccess: `php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com`
- php script: `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );`

<sup>(My web host does not allow modification of PHP via .htaccess so I tried the other 2 methods.)</sup>

However the [`session_regenerate_id(true);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) in my login.php conflicts with `session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"` in that after a header redirect, it empties the PHP session variable.

**login.php**

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }

// authentication codes...

session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header('Location: redirect.php');
exit;
```

**redirect.php**

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
var_dump($_SESSION); // returns array(0) { } if session.cookie_domain is set
```

I understand that using `true` in `session_regenerate_id()` would delete the old session, but it does not empty the session variable if `session.cookie_domain` is not set. Why is it so?

And the above 3 solutions do not work if I do not regenerate the session id, but doing so would result in session variable being emptied. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think your host would allow changing php.ini either, so you're basically left with `ini_set()` :)

Comment: Is your `login.php` missing a `session_start()` at the top?

Comment: @Jack I just called the host. They explicitly allowed me to work on php.ini. They just disabled some features in .htaccess only.

Comment: @Jack I have `session_start()` at the top of `login.php`.

Comment: put this at the top:
`error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);` for better debugging

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina No errors found related to the current issue.

Comment: can you share the code snippet where you use session functions for the first time

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina Those session functions are scattered around every page of the website. So instead of looking up every session function, I tested it right after `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`, before and just after `header('Location: redirect.php');`. The $_SESSION variable is good before the redirect. It is empty after `session_start()` in the redirected page. `if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }` almost always precedes every page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
setcookie('session_id', session_id(), 0, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
if( !empty($_SESSION["user_logged_in"]) ){
header("Location: home.php");
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Obviously `setcookie` is less secure, but if all three do not work for you that will help you out, you can use an additional session of the original domain or even store them in database if you want additional securuty along with setcookie option

Comment: Can you provide some explanation instead of only code? Thanks.

Comment: To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina I have `session_start()` at the top of `login.php`.

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina Alright the `setcookie` method would be a workaround, but it still doesn't explain what happened to the $_SESSION variable. I hope there is a $_SESSION solution though.

Comment: yeah, actually I'm trying different methods on wamp, but it is difficult to implement your situation in code, because my $_SESSION is not empty :)

Comment: it is very strange that sessions do not work on your web hosting, try to use curl to fetch the sessions from another person on that hosting

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina the $_SESSION is not empty in my localhost either, since I have no domain name to set in php.ini. This makes it hard for me to debug the code.

Comment: hmm, upvote my answer if it provides a solution, in the meanwhile I'll try other ways or may be even google it

Comment: @GLESPrateekNina I don't know who downvoted it, and it doesn't really answer the question, but I would upvote it for your continued effort.