# 2 different php sessions: www.domain.com and domain.com: How to consolidate?

Tags: php, session-variables

So after spending several hours ripping my hair out I finally realized the issue with my sessions. The session data was being written but the server was "silently" starting 2 sessions.

1) Firs session for all pages that are in the www.domain.com

2) And another one for just domain.com

How can I consolidate the 2 sessions and be sure that regardless of "www" or not, I am pulling the same session?

Thank you! Appreciate all help.

Comment: Configure your web server to redirect all traffic to one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that www  is practically a subdomain (to public readers: correct me if I am wrong), then maybe you can find useful information here:
[Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

Comment: The bigger problem is that the same content is available on www and the root domain. While you can configure php session cookies to work over subdomains, its preferable to ensure that all traffic is sent to just one instead of both domains.

Comment: What you say is probably true, but most websites I know of, allow for www to have the same content as the root (@), and that is becoming kind of a convention. It is a default in most web servers, as far as I know...

Comment: The general practice is to either redirect the root domain to www or vis versa. Having two domains causes problems like mentioned here and can result in issues with SEO.

Comment: You're probably right. Although, until today, most of the hosting accounts I have created allow both as a default. Nevertheless, I agree with you. The problem is that many users don't have the appropriate experience to configure that, especially when they start with a website, and then, before you know it, you have google results on both www and root. I have to admit that I am kind of twisted in the same twirl with my own website...