# Session not working on subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, session, session-variables

I have tried all these methods from here: [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

But session is not working on my subdomains. I am trying to share session within subdomain.domain.com and www.domain.com
Both are hosted on different IPs. Any idea how can I share session among them?
One is wordpress, another is a different script.

Comment: I will test this on my end to see if I get the same issue.