# php sessions to carry over to subdomains dont work

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain

I just read this link and try to implement it [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

in my localhost I have the following index.php file

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.localhost' );
if ("" === $_POST['login_name']){

}elseif ("" === $_POST['login_password']){

}else{
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['login_name'];
$_SESSION['group'] = 'support';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Idea Networks And Communications Limited</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" style="display:block;margin:0 auto">
<fieldset>
<legend>Please, Log In</legend>
<label >User Name</label>
<input name="login_name" type="text" maxlength="32" />
<br />
<label>Password</label>
<input name="login_password" type="password" maxlength="32" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
echo var_dump($_SESSION['login']);
echo var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
echo var_dump($_SESSION['group']);
?>
```

In subdomain.localhost I have the following index.php file

```
session_start();

echo var_dump($_SESSION['login']);
echo var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
echo var_dump($_SESSION['group']);
```

But they prints null value.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should use the following code instead of modifying the ini file:

this should be set before calling the session_start.
As you can see i didn't use ".localhost" use your host name instead.
If your going to test this code better to test this using Firefox because cookies with domains
will not work in chrome if the server is not located on the internet
for an instance the host name of my computer is "example-pc"

```
session_set_cookie_params (0, "/", ".example-pc", false, true);
```

then call the session start

```
session_start();
```

Comment: when accessing your application in subdomain you should type in (http:)//yoursubdomain.hostname