# Sharing a session to a subdomain - PHP

Tags: php

My user is logged in at `site_url.com` on a CMS, however I am now developing a mobile version of the site, outside the CMS on a subdomain `m.site_url.com` and would like the session to be synchronized with the CMS.

I have included a file with all the CMS' functions like this:

```
<?php include('/home/flyeurov/public_html/core/codon.config.php');
```

The subdomain `m.site_url.com` is located at `/public_html/mobile` directory. Inside `/mobile` is `index.php` and a trigger to display a dashboard or a login form, depending on user's state (logged in or not).

It is working, and I am able to login and see the dashboard, however only when I access direct path for example `site_url.com/mobile/index.php`. If I am logged in, and I access this path, it will take me to `crew_center.php` - the dashboard.

This does not happen when I access the subdomain at `m.site_url.com`. Even when I am logged in, I get shown `login.php` page.

Here is `index.php`:

```
<?php include('/home/flyeurov/public_html/core/codon.config.php');

session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site_url.com');

if(Auth::LoggedIn())
{
    header("Location: crew_center.php");
} 
else
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

I can therefore imagine that this is down to a session issue, but how can I share the CMS' session with the `m` subdomain?

Comment: There is no such thing as multisite sessions...

Comment: Is there any other way I can attempt to fix this then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a cookie!

When the user logs into their account at sitea.com, then set a cookie.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "COOKIE-VALUE", time()+3600, "/", "siteb.com");
```

This will set a cookie with this info contained in it:

```
Name: TestCookie
Value: COOKIE-VALUE
Expiration: One Hour
Cookie directory: /
Domain: siteb.com
```

The domain is set to siteb.com so that siteb can read the value contained in the cookie.

Now all you have to do is read the cookie at siteb.com!

**I do not recommend using cookies to hold passwords or banking information**, however, this is the only way that i see possible as a solution to your problem.

I hope this helps, let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a session id across domains, they are not designed to work that way (for security reasons). Although you can do what i have done in the past and store the session data in a serialised format in either a cookie, or as a `POST` variable within a form, or as base64 encoded serialised format as part of the URL.

```
<input type="hidden" name="session_data" value="<?php echo(base64_encode(serialize($_SESSION))); ?>"/>
```

or

```
<a href="http://sub.domain.com/?session_data=<?php echo(base64_encode(serialize($_SESSION))); ?>">Go Here</>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell the server to keep the session for the domain and not for the subdomains.
It can be achieved via ***ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'site_url.com');***

This will keep the session for the domain and the same session will be shared to all the subdomains.

Visit http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain

Comment: I do not recommend changing ini settings for this issue.

Comment: The php's  default ini setting will be override in the application. It will not affect the settings of other applications hosted in the same web server.