# How do I make $_SESSION consistent between subdomains?

Tags: php

I am using session in my website to authentication of user and check if user is logged in or not.

The problem is that if user login using http://example.com and after this user open the website by using http://www.example.com, the session is not available and he has to login again.

What can I do to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: Sorry, its duplicate question, I have solved my issue with suggestion question by @Itay , What I can do with this question??

Comment: session.cookie_domain = .domain.com

Comment: Note that it's best for SEO to redirect all traffic to a single domain, be it www or non-www

Answer (score 1):

I love how [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free) explains it.

> If your domain is www.example.org, you can host your static components on static.example.org. However, if you've already set cookies on the top-level domain example.org as opposed to www.example.org, then all the requests to static.example.org will include those cookies.

You have two options:

1. When users go to your website, redirect to www.*
2. [Have cookies effective on the top-level domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644934/)

The issue with having cookies work everywhere is that a cookie-less sub-domain will not work on the same domain.

> In this case, you can buy a whole new domain, host your static components there, and keep [that] domain cookie-free.