# User's can't login after changing session id cookie domain

Tags: php, subdomain, session-cookies

I've changed my session ID cookie domain so my sessions can be used on subdomains as per [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains).

However now my users can't login. I think the old cookie is still being sent and read by my PHP session_start().

Should I try and remove the old cookie? Or is something else going on here?

Also, it would be good if a solution didn't require me to rename my session id cookie.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Sorry I don't really have any code specific to the problem. It is a setting in php ini (session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"), then I call session_start() in my scripts.