# Passing session from sub-somain to domain

Tags: php, session

The directive `session.cookie_domain` has been set to `.test.site.com` on my server.

I'm using the following code to pass the session from `3rd level domain` to `2nd level domain` (ie, from `test.site.com` to `site.com`

```
$site = session_name("site");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.test.site.com');
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
}
```

but sessions aren't being passed from `test.site.com` to `site.com`

Any idea?

Comment: Try Setting the session.cookie_domain to site.com

Comment: @ opensource-ios, Then the parameter isn't downward domain level compatible? thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
```

This way the domain and all subdomains will have access to the session.

I don't know whether it's possible to limit it to the domain and one subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very familiar with

```
$site = session_name("site");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
}
```

but not

```
$site = session_name("site");
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.test.site.com');
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
}
```

When it's about to pass `sessions` across the upper & lower level domains.

**Lesson to learn:** `session.cookie_domain` should be set to the lowest possible common level that is 2nd level `(.site.com)` in order to pass the sessions across all other upper levels including `site.com`itself.