# PHP session.cookie_domain not setting PHPSESSID for localhost project URLs only

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to set the cookie domain for local URLs such as http://local-myproject and http://en.local-myproject, etc:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.local-myproject');
```

But when I check whether the PHPSESSID cookie was written for this domain, it is missing. Only when I remove this line does the cookie appear. But, I want to be able to share the cookie across subdomains. Does my browser (Chrome and FF) not like this value `.local-myproject` as a cookie domain? Does it have to be a valid URL? e.g. local-myproject.com (I could always create these for all my projects in /etc/hosts)

Comment: It should work fine. Are you using a linux server with Suhosin? If so, check out the answers/comments here http://stackoverflow.com/q/644920/1301076

Comment: No, doesn't appear to use it. I tried on my home laptop too and have the same issues. Strange.