# PHP How to allow subdomain to check for registered account?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made a website website.org and a subdomain for it subdomain.website.org. On the main domain, I have set up a user login system with a MySQL database. On the main domain, the php code can successfully check whether the user has logged in or not. However, since the registration/login page is inside the main domain directory, the webpages on the subdomain are unable to do the same. How do I make it so that both domains connect to the same database and check for the same account?

Comment: Just make sure you use the same DB credentials, as it is a subdomain it will be able to connect to the same database anyway

Comment: How do you check if the user is logged in or not? Using sessions?

Comment: databases don't care about what domain or sub-domain it's in (unless you've cookies/sessions happening). You need to post your code here. Question's unclear.

Comment: If you have trouble with get the user session on the subdomain, you should check the cookie settings for domain. Use ".website.org" as value to ensure the the cookie is readable by all subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from 4 methods:

Place this in your php.ini:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

Or in your .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

Or as the first thing in your script:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

Or in your php-fpm pool configuration for your site:

```
php_value[session.cookie_domain] = .example.com
```

you can view [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/644934/4853213)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply SSO(single site login) like google.
Please use cookies to store login user details. 
Once you login set cookie and use in subdomain.