# How to get oxwall session in another site

Tags: php, session, get, oxwall

I'm using oxwall software in my website which is free and open source community software and it is written in PHP...

The oxwall software works fine in my website, but what i'm trying to do is to get it's session and also the functions in a subdomain which isn't using oxwall software but in the same server (mysite.com to sub.mysite.com)

any help please? [oxwall in github](https://github.com/oxwall/oxwall)

Comment: If the software is just using php sessions, then this is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains

Comment: thank you @JonathanKuhn but i need to include the functions as well