# Lost $SESSION on subdomains header

Tags: php, session

I am trying for 8 hours to fix it, and this post doesn't help me: [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

I am losing my id session on a new sub.domains.com
Here is the code: from sub.domains.com

```
if($postac['zalogowany'] == 0){ $postac = ""; $_SESSION['postac'] = 0; }
```

login.php from domena.com

```
    if($doVariable == 'play' && $_POST['postac'] > 0) {
        if($_GET['serv'] == 'cos') 
            $server = 'baza';
        $_SESSION['postac'] = $_POST['postac'];
            $zalogowany = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE postac set zalogowany = 1 where id=:postac");  
            $zalogowany->bindValue(':postac', $_SESSION['postac'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
            $zalogowany->execute();
        if($_GET['serv'] == 'play');
            header("Location: http://sub.domains.com");
 }
```

Comment: can we see `var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());` ?

Comment: @Federkun from sub.domains.com array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) } the same is from domena.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change [session.cookie_domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) in your php.ini to allow the cookie to be read across the subdomains. You can also do it at runtime with [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php).

```
session.cookie_domain = ".domains.com"
```

Comment: where i can find php.ini ? i try locate php.ini but i got this locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory i have debian 8

Comment: i add session.cookie_domain = ".domena.com"  to /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini but doesn't work

Comment: have you rebooted the web server?

Comment: what's `var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());` now?

Comment: array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) }

Comment: `domain` is still an empty string, you didn't changed `session.cookie_domain` at all. Do it with `session_set_cookie_params`.

Comment: do you mean session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com'); 
session_start();  to everyfiles on sub.domains.com and on domena.com?

Comment: i change from session.cookie_domain = ".domains.com" to session_set_cookie_param and nothing changed still the same problem

Comment: now 
array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(12) "domena.com" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) } i add this to file session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'domena.com'); 
session_start();  

var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());

Comment: it should be `.domena.com` instead of `domena.com`. otherwise the cookie will be available only for `domena.com`.

Comment: ok i understand now i change in php.ini and now working array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(13) ".domena.com" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) } but $_SESSION id empty NULL

Comment: i again lost $_SESSION why? i arleady have the domain on string but its show like Failed to load resource: htttp:domena.com/somefiles/files.php the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)

Comment: That's an unrelated problem, you can open another question

Comment: but i lost too $_SESSION = null again why?