# PHP - Separate session on the same domain

Tags: php, session, dns

Is it possible to separate session on the same domain by looking based on a parameter in the url?

For example : mywebsite.com/mytheme1 has different session of mywebsite.com/mytheme2

Thank you

Comment: I miss read the question. No you cant..

Comment: the answer on this ticket is what you are looking for [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could namespace your sessions, by using different session names.

Here's an example that looks to see if a parameter is set in the URL, and changes the session name accordingly.

```
<?php

$name = isset($_GET['foo']) ? 'foo' : 'bar';
session_name($name);
session_start();
```

You could have different session mechanisms, utilising a similar strategy.