# PHP Sessions through subdomains when not allowed to edit php.ini

Tags: php, ini

My host (one) is not allowing me to change the php.ini file and nor can I find it (I probably don't have read access to it even). When I am trying to make session variables go across subdomains I can't since the session cookie is set for the main domain only (`example.com`). I would like it to be set for `.example.com`

I have tried to set the php ini file to allow this.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');
```

That did not work because I am not allowed to run the `ini_set()` function. I also tried finding the php.ini file but could not find it in my FTP client. Using `phpinfo()` wields me it is in `/etc/php` but I don't have access to that directory.

I expect this to work but clearly it does not. Checking the developer console in Firefox the domain path for the `PHPSESSID` cookie is still `example.com` and not `.example.com`

Is there any workaround other than setting the session variables on the correct subdomain from the start?

Comment: No sane shared hosting service allows customers to fiddle with the system-wide PHP settings but it's almost always unnecesary given that you can use `.htaccess`, `.user.ini` or `ini_set()` for most purposes. However, if `ini_set()` itself has been banned (that's what you mean, don't you?), it's a clear indication that they don't want you to customise anything. If so, finding a way may result in account termination due to violation of terms of use. Probably it's not even a multi-site plan. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Session cookie params can also be set with [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). The domain is the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ini variable like this before **session_start()**

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

or for that question you can set in htaccess file like this:

```
php_value session.cookie_domain .example.com
```

and from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9434158/3415984):

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
        session_id($_COOKIE['session_id']);
    Zend_Session::start(); //or session_start();
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['session_id']))
        setcookie('session_id', session_id(), 0, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```

at the end if any of this ways doesn't work, you can change the **session_name**

```
 session_name('example_name');
```

then use the following code into the php page

```
session_set_cookie_params(0,"/",".example.com",FALSE,FALSE);
setcookie(session_name(), session_id(),0,"/","example.com");
session_start();
```

for more information see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)

Comment: Clearly you did not read my post. I am not allowed to run the `ini_set` function. The .htaccess method does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the best solution !**

Regarding your situation and if you cannot set it using .htaccess, you can make a redirect to your subdomain(s), create the session and redirect back to the URL where you want to be,

EX :
example.com -> any action -> go to sub1.example.com -> create session -> go to sub2.example.com -> create session -> ... -> go to example.com

Or :
You can also create pixel image with links to your subdomains if you don't want to use redirect

For this two solutions to work, you need to set sessions separately for each subdomain.