# session.cookie_domain not working as expected in Plesk / PHP application on 2 subdomains

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, plesk

*Edit 29/1/2019 - this question was eligible for a bounty but none of the provided answers directly address the issue. If you have an answer that works based on what's been asked please respond*

I have 2 domains configured on the same physical server:

```
app.example.com
help.app.example.com
```

Users login to `https://app.example.com/` which consists of PHP 5.5 application which stores some data in the `$_SESSION` array after a successful login.

I want to configure `https://help.app.example.com/` so that I can read the session data present on `https://app.example.com/`. The application on the `help` subdomain is a content management system built in PHP 7.

In Plesk I have added the following to 'Additional configuration directives' for `php.ini` under *both* `app.example.com` and `help.app.example.com`:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

If I upload a `phpinfo()` script to `help.app.example.com` it is showing the following for `session.cookie_domain`:

- Local value: no value
- Master value: `.example.com`

If I then run the following in a script on `help.app.example.com`:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
die;
?>
```

It is outputting an empty array:

```
array(0) { }
```

However, if I run the equivalent on `app.example.com` it is outputting an array of session data which shows details of the logged-in user (as expected):

```
array(15) {
   ["o_id"]=> (1) "1"
   ["u_id"]=> string(4) "1745"
   ...
}
```

I'm expecting to see the same output on both sub-domains. Why is this not working?

I have read [Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains) but none of that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this not working?

by default sessions are saved to local files on the server, location of which is specified in php.ini's `session.save_path`, for example `session.save_path = /var/lib/php/sessions`, if app.example.com and help.app.example.com are running on 2 different servers with their own filesystem, or even if it's running on the same filesystem but have different `session.save_path` directives in php.ini, they won't share the same $_SESSION.

if you want 2 different servers to share the same $_SESSION, possible solutions include creating a shared session store database with `session_set_save_handler()` (like MongoDB or MySQL comes to mind), or creating a networked filesystem and set `session.save_path = /path/to/networked/filesystem/mountpoint` in php.ini, but both of these methods may incur a significant performance penalty..

... since the cookie is shared across both domains, `session_id()` will return the same value on both sides, that could be used as an id for a session database, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

<strike>(i'd write a sample class if i had more time but i'm out of time)</strike>

switch to a sql-db-backed session store (like MariaDB, MySQL, or PostgreSQL), for example:
schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions (
  id VARCHAR(255) ,
  atime BIGINT ,
  data BLOB
)
```

SessionHandlerInterface implementation:

```
class MySqlSessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct(string $dsn, string $username, string $password)
    {
        $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));
    }
    protected function a(string $id) : bool
    {
        $ret = $this->db->query("UPDATE sessions SET atime = " . (time()) . " WHERE id = " . $this->db->quote($id));
        return ($ret->rowCount() > 0);
    }
    public function close() : bool
    {
        // TODO: implement locking/race-condition-free session handling?
        return true;
    }
    public function destroy(string $id) : bool
    {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = " . $db->quote($id));
        return true;
    }
    public function gc(int $maxlifetime) : int
    {
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE atime < " . (time() - $maxlifetime));
        return 1; // ??? not sure what this return int is supposed to contain, docs doesn't say either
    }
    public function open(string $save_path, string $session_name) : bool
    {
        if (!$this->a($session_name)) {
            $stm = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions (id,atime,data) VALUES(?,?,?);");
            $stm->execute(array($session_name, time(), serialize(null)));
        }
        return true;
    }
    public function read(string $session_id) : string
    {
        if (!$this->a($session_id)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("supplied session id does not exist.");
        }
        return $this->db->query("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = " . $this->db->quote($session_id))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['data'];
    }
    public function write(string $session_id, string $session_data) : bool
    {
        // optimization note: this function can be optimized to do everything in a single query, instead of using a() (which also use a query)
        if (!$this->a($session_id)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("supplied session id does not exist.");
        }
        $stm = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE sessions SET data = ? WHERE id = ?");
        $stm->execute(array($session_data, $session_id));
        return true;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
// for DSN documentation, check http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php
$handler = new MySqlSessionHandler ('mysql:host=mydb.foo.com;dbname=sessions;charset=utf8mb4','MySqlUsername','MySqlPassword');
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
```

- now they should definitely share sessions..
- warning: untested as of writing, but this should work in theory.

Comment: Both domains are on the same physical server as per the question. The `session.save_path` is exactly the same for both (`/var/lib/php/session`)

Comment: @Andy weird. still, if you change to a sqldb-backed session store, do they share sessions then? re-read my answer, i added an example of sql-db-based session storage which should be compatible with MySQL and MariaDB and PostgreSQL

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer and providing database session storage code. However, clearly this isn't the solution I'm looking for. I'm asking about sharing the session data *without using a database at all*, particularly as this would require changing application code when this shouldn't be necessary. I know it's possible to read `$_SESSION` between applications on subdomains (without using a database) as I have done it before. However for some reason it isn't working under my current set up and am trying to debug it and work out why.

Answer (score 0):

I just try to replicate whit:

- Product: Plesk Onyx 17.8.11 Update #37
- PHP Version 7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

and works pretty fine. I got values in _Session array in both cases, even I just save the values only in the subdomain.

In my set, the 'Additional configuration directives' for php.ini is the same for the domain and the subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. This doesn't really give me much helpful information though. You're saying it works for you; well it doesn't for  me and I'm still none the wiser as to why.