# session variable from another page is not visible on a subdomain

Tags: php, session

**login.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['aid'] = 1;
echo $_SESSION['aid']; // 1
```

then **index.php**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['aid']; // nothing is echoed  
$_SESSION['test'] = 323;
echo $_SESSION['test']; // 323
```

**error_log**

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: aid in...`

this happens only on my subdomain - admin.example.com
on main domain - example.com - everything is ok
also this happens only on remote server
on my localhost - `xampp, win7, chrome` - it's ok

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the cookie domain to ".example.com" before you start your session (on all scripts on all subdomains,
else the cookie is not even valid on a different (sub)domain.

`session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`

Or make use of [session_set_cookie_params()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
session_start();
```

See also this question:
[Allow php sessions to carry over to subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644920/allow-php-sessions-to-carry-over-to-subdomains)